# How to build a hybrid app as enterprise app

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play-services, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a hybrid app that requires an enterprise deployment that means it just needs to be deployed to some specific users in company and not public at all.
Something like it will depend on device id or something unique to make app run on user's device.
Can AppStore or Google Play implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, Apps can be deployed using an `Enterprise` in house profile.
(https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apd29c0f45f1)

Enterprise Apps have no limitation regarding the device ID installing the app, but are usually used in combination with a MDM controller, which enforce this part of the security.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Google Play Private Channel is what you are looking for:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

> The Google Play Private Channel is a feature of the Google Play Store which lets you distribute Android apps internally to users in your Google Apps domain.
>   Hosting internal apps on the Private Channel allows you to control which users or user groups can download the apps.